# Max of random variable

Tags: probability

> If $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim Exp(\mu)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, determine $P(X=\max\{X,Y\})$.
>
> Solution:
>
> $$\begin{align}&P\big(X=\max\{X,Y\}\big)\\=&1-P\big(X=\min\{X,Y\}\big)\\=&1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\\=&\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\end{align}$$

I'm confused as to how $P\big(X=\min\{X,Y\}\big)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$. I know that $X$ can only be either the $\min$ or $\max$ of $\{X,Y\}$ but I still don't get how the expression is obtained $\big(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\big)$.

Comment: Do you have the independence of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, will edit that in.

Comment: Since $X,Y$ are independent, $P(X=min(X,Y)) = P(X \leq Y)$ Can u compute it?

Comment: @Presage and $P(X=\max(X,Y))=P(Y\leq X)$ (same stuff with only $\mu$ and $\lambda$ switched). I really see no reason here to go after the probability of the complement.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233955/how-to-compute-pxy-if-x-and-y-are-independent-and-exponentially-distrib for how to find $P(X > Y)$.

Comment: @drhab Only reason I can imagine, is that maybe somewhere earlier in the book/note that the question is from, $P(X<Y)$ is computed for $X,Y$ exponential and independent

Comment: @Presage you're right, it's supposedly taken from https://i.imgur.com/OzuRf0j.png but I also don't quite understand how it is gotten and how it ties in with this.

Comment: Should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @zuwapito there is no evident/simple route to deduce probability $P(X=\min(X,Y))$ from what is mentioned in the link of your comment.

Comment: The preference to the minimum may be justified in the context of merging of independent Poisson processes. Other than that, I see no apparent reason to consider the complementaru probability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a special reason to go for $P(A)=1-P(A^{\complement})$ here.

You can go directly for:

$$P\left(X=\max\left(X,Y\right)\right)=P\left(Y\leq X\right)=\int P\left(Y\leq X\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\;dy=$$$$\int P\left(y\leq X\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\;dy=\int P\left(y\leq X\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)\;dy$$where the last equality is based on independence.

Substitution gives:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda y}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy=\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\lambda+\mu\right)y}dy=\mu\left[\frac{-e^{-\left(\lambda+\mu\right)}}{\lambda+\mu}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$$